# Is there a Scope for updating agent pool metadata?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I would like to programmatically update the metadata (Details) of my agent pools, with some javascript code like this:

```
let base64 = Buffer.from(`:${token}`).toString('base64');
let response = await fetch(`https://dev.azure.com/AcmeCorp/_apis/distributedtask/pools/${poolId}/poolmetadata?api-version=6.0-preview`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: text,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/text',
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${base64}`
    }
});
```

This works fine, but only if I use a Personal Access Token with *Full Access* - if I create a scoped token, granting "Read & Manage Agent Pools" still gives me a 401 Auth error.

Is there a way to give a scoped token access to update agent pool metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, not only `Read & Manage` for **Agent Pools**, but I also tried to select `all the scopes` via `Custom defined`, not work.

[image]

[image]

It just works with `Full access`.

[image]

Looks like it is a product issue, you could report the problem in this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21&preview2=true).

Comment: Ah Ok... I'll accept this answer, as it seems there's nothing else to do.  I have filed the same issue at the link you provided.